# How to fix hikariPool connection timeout with sql-server?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, hikaricp

I have a Java/Spring app that uses JDBC and HikariCP with a SQL Server instance,

I found this warning to occur too frequently in the logs:

> HikariPool-2 - Failed to validate connection ConnectionID:2483
> ClientConnectionId: c8a86a9c-b804-4060-a118-01378e040b59 (The
> connection is closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime
> value."

To solve this I tried to configure the data source as this:

```
jdbc-url: "jdbc:sqlserver://my-db.dev.aws-some-db.com;databaseName=MYHUGEDB"
username: "someUsername"
password: "somePassword"
maximumPoolSize: "10"
maxLifetime: "60000"
keepaliveTime: "40000"
```

I choose the maxLifeTime to be less then the SQL Server query time out,

To find the SQL Server time, I executed this SQL query:

```
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'remote query timeout'
```

It returns:

- config_value: 600 (s)
- run_value: 600 (s)

Normally 600s > 60000(ms), so it should not raise this warn, but it did. Why?

Comment: The `remote query timeout` option doesn't affect what you think it does. It affects outgoing connections from the SQL Server itself to other data sources, such as via Linked Servers, OPENQUERY, etc..

Comment: So why are you actually setting the `maxLifetime` and `keepaliveTime` properties? Are you running on network infrastructure that actively drops SQL network connections on a periodic basis? Because by default SQL Server itself doesn't ever close client connections after any particular time.

Comment: I thought it is the equivalent of "wait_timeout" in mysql, which after the connection in pool will be no longer valid, in fact maxLifeTime properties are required if the sql server define a timeout policy

Comment: Connection Pools are a client-side construct. They have nothing to do with server-side policies. Please provide a SQL Server documentation link showing how to affect timeouts on incoming connections.

Comment: maxLifeTime depends on infrastructure timeout limit (such as wait_timeout in the case of mysql), you can take took at  HikariCP documentation : https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: HikariCP is client-side, and you're talking about MySQL policies. MySQL != Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I didnt understand your point of view, if it is a client-side it means isn't related to server ?  client-side parameters depends on infrastructure (for example we can not put any username)  because it is simply a client :)  I gave mysql as an example for analogy purpose, I know very well that MySQL != MS SQL Server :)

Comment: @maroodb Can you provide the source where you found the link between `maxLifetime` and the query you provided `EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'remote query timeout'` ?

Comment: Also a quick tip: try trace logging or debugging the Hikari configs to make sure your configurations are actually getting set as you intended.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning How would you verify SQL Server is using the default as you described `by default SQL Server itself doesn't ever close client connections after any particular time`? Is there some type of UI/Tool/Query I can use to verify this?